# s ParseUser.CurrentUser() different on Parses servers from Client Side

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, pfuser

While working with objects, I am trying to compare one field of a queried object to the current user using the app

I was using an IF loop

```
if( ParseUser.CurrentUser() == object.getString("User"))
{
Do this
}
```

However, `ParseUser.CurrentUser` does not return in string format. So I declared a varible and tried that

```
String parseUser = ParseUser.CurrentUser.toString();
```

However, the string contains a completely different value then what the parse user for that particular user is called on the Parse server. Does something different happen on the server? Is there a correct way to return the `ParseUser.CurrentUser` in a string form?

Answer (score 1):

ParseUser.getCurrentUser() returns a ParseUser Object, not a String. So what you want to do is compare the ObjectId of the current user object to your user String.

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
if (currentUser != null && currentUser.getObjectId().equals(object.getString("User")){
     //do stuff
}
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: my one question is when i say object.getString("user") wouldn't I have to query for an object at somepoint? Would I be querying the user cass?